# Remote deployment in tomcat 6.0.14 server

Tags: tomcat, deployment, ant, build

I am looking for live tutorials or steps to do remote deployment in tomcat 6.0.14 application server. I already have a spring2 based webapp which is manually deployed via ant script - i want to automate it . How can i do remote deployment, remote start and remote stop of tomcat 6.0.14 server (running in a windows VM) from my windows desktop PC ?

Samples will be helpful .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the `ANT` script which deploys application remotely to tomcat:

```
<target name="tomcat-deploy-war" description="Deploy the App to Tomcat">
    <deploy url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
            username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
            password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
            path="${web.context.path}"
            war="file:${build.destdir}/${web.war.name}.war"/>
  </target>
```

[This post](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/bill/entry/ant_stuff_for_tomcat_remote) contains all information you need.